# How to get number of unread messages like whatsapp.?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Something like this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuZmV.jpg)

I want the message counter like the image above. In fact, I am able to get the message count but the problem is that the counter layout is visible to every item row.I want the counter layout to be visible to those row which contains unread messages.

Comment: please include actual code in your post too

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: i think a simple if condition will do your work. If counter is 0 you can make your view gone and let it visible when counter is greater than 0

Comment: I have tried it's showing on all the itemviews